# Change iOS devices make iOS app crash

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have built an `iPhone/iPod` app in Xamarin, which could run on iPads too. 
But now I have a bug from one of my customers, which occurs, when choosing pictures from iPad Air and iPad Mini. I searching for a hotfix, but I could see, I have to change the Devices to `Universal`.

But that change let to another runtime bug telling me

```
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path '/Users/udvikling/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E9486AE7-8E88-417C-B2BF-D38827F85CF5/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BC6F0AC-DA61-4894-A521-1F7FBF013297/<project>.app/LaunchScreen.storyboardc'
Native stack trace:
   0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a926d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010addbdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
   2   UIKit                               0x0000000102419d3d -[UIStoryboard name] + 0
   3   UIKit                               0x0000000101cd787b -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 58
   4   UIKit                               0x0000000101cd7bcf -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 260
   5   UIKit                               0x0000000101cd63ef -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1392
   6   UIKit                               0x0000000101cd3714 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
   7   FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001100e88c8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
   8   FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001100e8741 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 178
   9   FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001100e8aca -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
   10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a84c301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
   11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a84222c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
   12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a8416e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
   13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a8410f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
   14  UIKit                               0x0000000101cd2f21 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
   15  UIKit                               0x0000000101cd7f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
   16  ???                                 0x000000011c4c962c 0x0 + 4769748524
   17  ???                                 0x000000011c4c929d 0x0 + 4769747613
```

I tried changing the `Main interface` to what is set for `iPhone` but without success.
So what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your `deployment info`

your device should be set to `universal`.

Your `main interface` should be set to `main` not `launchscreen`.

and under `app icons and launchscreen images`,

`launchscreen file` should be set to `launch screen` and not `main`.

and make sure that you have both storyboard available in your project with respective name.

Comment: I only have empty and `LaunchScreen.storyboard` to choose from. Or do I have to open in Xamarin Studio and not Visual Studio? 
I do not have `app icons and launchscreen images` section but `Universal Icons` section.